# Google analytics is not picking up 100% of active users by report

Tags: google-analytics

I made a report of access to custom users and only 25% of users appear, the other 75% I do not know what happened.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a bit more details: what report(s) are you looking at, what secondary dimension is applied, what filters are applied?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the free version of Google Analytics?  If so, your data is likely getting sampled.  Try reducing your date range to just a day or two and see if it shows 100% of users.  You can also try simplifying your segment so that you are looking at fewer data points.  Here are the [Google docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en) explaining sampling.

Comment: it's like this
https://i.imgur.com/9qoMFSX.png
and
https://i.imgur.com/F8Q0eNN.png

Comment: What is the date range that you are using when you view your custom report?

Comment: I filtered for a week

Comment: If you remove the active users criteria, does it fix your issue?

Comment: it is like this
https://imgur.com/eSnDqMt
and
https://imgur.com/SflVe1F

Answer (score 1):

Your report only matches a portion of your traffic. Maybe you have a report filter, or maybe you are using a segment. This can also happen if you are trying to use a metric/dimension that only a portion of your traffic has. eg: Trying to see users by EventCategory will only include the users that had at least one event, not necessarily the same as the total number of users on your site.